Is there a way to make custom proactive events / notifications for my alexa skill?
As of right now I am able to get proactive events working as I need because it is in regards to packages which amazon provides a schema for in their proactive events api.
I now need it for the purpose of notifying the alexa that there is someone at the door (similar to a ring doorbell) and the closest i can get is by using the message alert schema. My goal is to just make a fully custom schema for the proactive event or to find out if there is another way to send a notification with a card and announcement similar to how the proactive events do so
I currently have this in my POST request but using all of the amazon documentation I cannot seem to find anything that works for a regular skills account. I know you can do notifications if you are a Alexa Smart Properties partner but I don't have the access unfourtunatley.
Current code:
 "event": {
        "name": "AMAZON.MessageAlert.Activated",
        "payload": {
          "state": {
            "status": "UNREAD",
            "freshness": "NEW"
          },
          "messageGroup": {
            "creator": {
              "name": "Test"
            },
            "count": 1
          }
        }
      

Output: "You have 1 new unread message from Test"
The issue with this is that the notification audio says this:
"1 New notification from Test: You have 1 new unread message from Test"
so the issue is that this seems to duplicate the audio output. If there is a way to fix that then that would also be a valid solution for myself

Unfortunately not, all you have are the fixed schema.  The predecessor to Proactive Notifications (now not available) had free-format notification speech, so you could issue whatever speech you wanted.  Amazon changed that to fixed schema when Proactive Notifications went live.

@allthepies do you know what the predecessor was called?

Notifications API I think.  I can still use it as I was in the initial developer preview and so can issue notifications with free-form speech.
